# What is the best way to strip HTML tags from a python list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup, I have:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= "http://scores.espn.go.com/ncb/playbyplay?gameId=400551234"
import urllib2
page= urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup= BeautifulSoup(page)
tr_tags= soup.findAll("tr", attrs={"class": True})
for tag in tr_tags:
    if "even"  in tag["class"]:td_tagsa=soup.findAll("td")
    if "odd"  in tag["class"]:td_tagsb=soup.findAll("td")
td_tagsa.extend(td_tagsb)
td_tags=td_tagsa
a=''.join(td_tags.stripped_strings)
```

At this point I try the stripped_strings command and get an error

```
'list' object has no attribute 'stripped_strings'
```

Yet when I try to join the elements into a str without stripping the HTML:

```
a=''.join(td_tags)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Tag found
```

It seems as though once BeautifulSoup outputs a list, the html is locked in. Is there a way I can rid myself of the HTML tags after using the findAll command in the beginning?

Comment: You are not calling `stripped_strings` on a BeautifulSoup element. Perhaps you wanted to apply that to *each element of the list* instead?

Comment: So where in the if statements should i put the stripped_strings command?

Comment: You haven't shown us where you use it *now*.

Comment: What @MartijnPieters is basically trying to tell you, if you haven't figured it out, is you're not posting your code with the `stripped_strings` in it. Posting all your attempts will greatly help us in understanding your problem fully. Also, personally, if you're trying to replicate the table, there are much easier ways than what you're doing.

Comment: I ended with the command a=''.join(td_tags.stripped.strings)

But if there is an easier way, it would be helpful, @Nanashi

Comment: Edit your code to include the change, unless you want us to edit it for you if you can't (don't know if your rep will allow it). Also, skip the `stripped_strings`, I say. I'd much rather find all the `td` tags inside each `tr` in `tr_tags`. That's much easier to manipulate and understand.

Comment: @Nanashi OP should be able to edit his post as users can always edit their own posts

Comment: can you explain how to find all the td inside each tr please. I was able to but then couldn't strip the tags

Comment: Posting an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, download and install the `Requests` library: [Link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It's generally easier to use than `urllib2` and it's got all manners of goodies that can be used for scraping.

Second, you should really master the essentials of `BeautifulSoup` and list comprehension in general. I'm assuming you didn't bother with the documentation because if you did, you would have known that `get_text()` would have gotten the text inside the element.

That said, my code is below. I used the `Requests` and `csv` libraries. This is pretty much an advanced version of what you're doing, seeing as to how it outputs the results to a file right away. Make sure you read and understand the comments. I've basically done the job for you so the least you can do is go through the code and *understand every line of it*.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq
import csv

## Create a soup from the URL's markup.
url = "http://scores.espn.go.com/ncb/playbyplay?gameId=400551234"
r = rq.get(url)
soup = bsoup(r.content)

## Find all the rows that have classes. Remove the first one -- it's irrelevant.
trs = soup.find_all("tr", class_=True)[1:]

## Main procedure.
with open("scores.csv", "wb") as ofile:

    f = csv.writer(ofile)

    ## Write the headers. 
    f.writerow(["Time","Kentucky","Score","Connecticut"])

    ## For every tr tag in trs, there are anywhere from 2-4 td tags, depending
    ## on what is shown in the markup. For some rows, the third and fourth td
    ## elements don't exist (td[2] and td[3]). This is why we're going to use
    ## a simple try-except-finally block to properly catch this possibility.
    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all("td")
        time = tds[0].get_text().encode("utf-8")
        kentucky = tds[1].get_text().encode("utf-8")
        ## The following two columns don't always exist (ie. "End of Game" type of lines)
        ## We'll attempt to get them. However, if an error occurs...
        try:
            score = tds[2].get_text().encode("utf-8")
            connecticut = tds[3].get_text().encode("utf-8")
        ## ... We assign them an empty string.
        except:
            score = ""
            connecticut = ""
        ## Finally, regardless of whether there are 2 or more td elements found, we
        ## write the result to the CSV file.
        finally:
            f.writerow([time,kentucky,score,connecticut])
```

The above will create a file named `scores.csv` in the folder where the script is stored. Check it, clean it, what have you. Just make sure you understand the code before you celebrate. ;)

Let us know if this helps.